# Interface not being applied when Error class is extended in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an `Exception1` class that extends the `Error` class of JavaScript, along with that it also implements an interface `SampleInterface`

```js
interface SampleInterface {
    func(): string;
}

class SampleClass {
    public message: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class Exception1 extends Error implements SampleInterface  {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message);
    }

    public func(): string {
        return "Exception1"
    }
}
```

On executing `console.log(new Exception1('a').func())` in the console I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).func is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:33
```

However this works as expected if the class extends some other class for example

```
class Exception2 extends SampleClass implements SampleInterface  {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message);
    }

    public func(): string {
        return "Exception2"
    }
}
```

On executing `console.log(new Exception2('a').func())` I get the expected output `Exception2`

Comment: check this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work

Comment: okay yeah this solves the problem, put it up as answer and i'll mark accepted. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend built-in types like `Array`, `Error`, or `Map`, the prototype chain is a bit messed up, which you need to fix explicitly, so that the members defined in your class become available to the instances of your class. This is pointed out in the [TypeScript docu](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work).

So, in order to fix this, you need to do something like below:

```
interface SampleInterface {
    func(): string;
}

class Exception1 extends Error implements SampleInterface  {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message);

        // Explicitly fix the prototype chain
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Exception1.prototype);
    }

    public func(): string {
        return "Exception1"
    }
}

console.log(new Exception1('a').func()) // and now it works
```